# Trying to understand IOC and binding

Tags: c#-4.0, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, structuremap

I am very new to concept of IOC and I understand the fact that they help us resolve different classes in different contexts. Your calling class will just interact with Interface and Interface with decide which implementation to give you and it takes care of newing up the object.

Please do correct me if I am understanding is wrong because my question is based on that:

Now, I see this pattern very often in these projects:

```
private readonly IEmailService emailService;
private readonly ITemplateRenderer templateRenderer;
private readonly IHtmlToTextTransformer htmlToTextTransformer;

public TemplateEmailService(IEmailService emailService,
    ITemplateRenderer templateRenderer,
    IHtmlToTextTransformer htmlToTextTransformer)
{
    this.emailService = emailService;
    this.htmlToTextTransformer = htmlToTextTransformer;
    this.templateRenderer = templateRenderer;
}
```

I understand that this helps using all the implementations of these classes without newing them up and also  you don't have to decide WHICH implementaion to get, your IOC decides it for you, right?

but when I code like this, I do not even touch any IOC congiguration files. And again I am usin git for 2 days only but from all the tutorials that I have read, I was expecting my self to configure something which says "Resolve IParent to Child" class. But it works without me doing anything like it. Is it because there is only one implementaion of these interfaces? and If I do have more than one implementations then and then only I will have to configure resolved explicitly?

Comment: Well, I figured..when there is ONLY one implementation of a particular Interface, IOC will figure out on its own(atleast structure map does that). You have to do explicit configuration only and only when there are multiple implementations of it.

Comment: Some IoC and DI frameworks also use "Convention over configuration" paradigm. So if you have interface IFoo and class Foo, which implements this interface, then framework will resolve IFoo to Foo without any configuration even if you have other classes, that implements IFoo. Actually it can be more complicated, but this is the main idea. As i know, it was originally invented in Ruby On Rails and structure map supports it too (http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2009/01/20/create-your-own-auto-registration-convention-with-structuremap/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code sample you have is a case of [Constructor Injection](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#ConstructorInjectionWithPicocontainer).

In a traditional code, you would have a parameterless constructor, and in it you would "new-up" your objects like this:

```
IEmailService emailService = new EmailService();
```

So your code is explictly controlling which implementation gets assigned to the interface variable.

In IoC using constructor injection, control is inverted, meaning the container is "driving the bus" and is creating your TemplateEmailService object. When it is about to create it, the container looks at your constructor parameters (IEmailService , ITemplateRenderer , etc.) and feeds those objects to your class for use.

The IoC container can be configured so that interface A gets fulfilled by implementation B (or C) explicitly. Each one has a way to do it. Or it could do it by convention (IFoo fulfilled by Foo), or even attributes in classes, whatever.

So to answer your question-- you can explicitly define which implementations get used to fulfill certain interfaces. Got to read the IoC container docs for how to.

One more thing - "when you code like this", you technically don't have to be using an IoC container. In fact, your class should not have a direct reference to the container - it will maximize the reusability, and also allow easy testing. So you would wire-up interfaces to implementation classes elsewhere.